# PGI Flang github disappeared

Tags: compiler-construction, fortran, llvm, pgi

Does anyone know where Flang or PGI/LLNL/Nvidia's Fortran for LLVM (not dragonegg) went to? I found some documentation to a github page that no longer exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/flang-compiler has been online for a few weeks.  That's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It didn't go anywhere, it's just not yet been made publicly available.  I asked our FLANG team and they said that it's should be opened up to the public sometime in the next few months.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like https://github.com/llvm-flang may be what you want, but it hasn't been updated in two years. I found a PDF presentation from November 2016 that suggested development was ongoing, but it has no links.

Comment: That's the other i.e. non-PGI Flang.  Last time I looked, that front-end could compile LAPACK but not much else in terms of Fortran 90+.

Answer (score 0):

Flang has been released under Apache 2.0 license: https://github.com/flang-compiler/flang
Here is the [announcement](http://lists.flang-compiler.org/pipermail/flang-announce_lists.flang-compiler.org/2017-August/000001.html).